# Getting Twitter followers images with PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am totally new to the twitter API, and I am trying to get all of my followers images to display them on my site, but the documentation on twitter.com has just confused me even more.

I am using PHP, and as far as I can tell I need to register an application, get a library that is suited to my needs, and them proceed to create my application.

The only problem with that is that I have no idea how to authenticate using OAuth, if anyone could shine some light on this matter, post a code snippit of how I can get all of the followers pics or maybe even point me to some useful tutorials or resources, that would be a great help.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is at the official Twitter API Docs at http://dev.twitter.com/doc

Like you already pointed out, you are supposed to [get a library for interfacing with the Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php). These libraries usually have means to authenticate via OAuth as well, for instance you can use Zend Framework's [`Zend_OAuth`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html) component to authenticate and then use the access token to talk to the Twitter API with [`Zend_Service_Twitter`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html).

Comment: @user you're welcome. Just try to get it working with your library of choice. If you find you'll still run into trouble then, feel free to ask a new question, showing some relevant code snippets of what you've tried and what's not working.